# How-to setup a traffic control server

Tags: networking, iptables, centos6, network-traffic

I am trying to set up a traffic control server between the network and the firewall-router.
The server has two network devices:
Firewall <--> Server <---> NETWORK

It is running CentOS 6.4 x64 and I would like to use Etherape.
My idea is to have eth0 connected directly to our router and eth1 to our network.
eth1 would have two virtual interfaces, one with an IP to ssh the server and the other just forwarding with IPTables to eth0 with no IP. Of course, eth0 would not have any IP (we don't want to change the Gateway).

Any suggestion or better way to do this?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally it was quite easy. Install brctl and etherape, then:

brctl addbr br0
brctl stp br0 off
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig eth1 up
ifconfig br0 up
service network restart
ifconfig br0 XX.YY.ZZ.AA

That is a temporal configuration. If you reboot you have to re-do it. Here is a way to make it persistent:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Ethernet-Bridge-netfilter-HOWTO.html#toc3.3

Finally, (installing if you are in a Windows Box, Xming and Putty and) connecting as root to XX.YY.ZZ.AA with X11 redirection, execute etherape and you will have you remote traffic control.

To make it easier, I will recommend to add the filter:
ip and not ((src net XX.YY.ZZ.AA) or dst net XX.YY.ZZ.AA)
To avoid the X11 traffic between the server and your box.

Comment: You also have to disable iptables, of course! If not, you will have the firewall blocking everything!